# Consequence of stress-energy tensor vanishing on-shell?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, correlation-functions

Let's say we have a QFT, which off-shell has a non-zero stress-energy tensor, but vanishes when the equations of motion are applied.

If the stress-energy tensor vanishes *off*-shell, then all field operators are necessarily spacetime independent. But what can we say about the fields spacetime dependence when it only vanishes on-shell?

My guess is that the fields can be considered constant at separated points in correlation functions, but receives delta function contributions. So the two-point correlator would be

$$\langle\Phi_1(x)\Phi_2(y)\rangle=A_{12}+B_{12}\delta(x-y).$$

Where $A_{12}$ is some constant and $B_{12}$ could potentially be some polynomial in derivatives.